# Read local storage from nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm running a web app behind nginx setup as reverse proxy. The user's [JWT](https://jwt.io/) is stored in the browser's local storage.

Is it possible (and if yes, how?) to read the token as stored in the browser's local storage upon requests in nginx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Browser's Local storage doesn't get transmitted with a request. You will need to modify the request to first read the jwt from localstorage then apply that to the request.

Since no language was tagged I will provide a basic *off the cuff* javascript example

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        var myProp = localStorage.myProperty;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', myProp); 
    }
});
```